# Problem with ilasm

Tags: c#, .net, compilation, dotfuscator, ilasm

I have a quite big program in .net 3.5 SP1 which is compiling just fine.
However when I want to obfuscate it with Obfuscator Pro (evaluation for now), Obfuscator stops with the following error:

> [Build Output] This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
>   [Build Output] Please contact the application's support team for more information.
>   [Build Output] ilasm returned 3
>   [Build Output] Build Error.

Since the error comes from ILASM, I thought lets do what Obfuscator does (w/o obfuscation) and executed the following commands:

> => ildasm.exe /OUT=C:\MyApp.exe.il /TEXT /NOBAR /RAWEH /QUOTEALLNAMES /UTF8 /LINENUM /FORWARD C:\MyApp\bin\Release\MyApp.exe
>   => ilasm C:\MyApp.exe.il

The first command (ILDASM) passes just fine, I get a 450MB IL file.
The second command (ILASM) however crashes with the following error:

> This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
>   Please contact the application's support team for more information.

Does anybody have any idea what the error could be?
My system is Windows 7 x64 with the tools from Visual Studio 2008 (SP1).

UPDATE:
I contacted Obfuscator support and did some tests for them. They have really helpful people there by the way.
We've discovered that the error happens only when using the x86 ILASM from the .net 2.0 framework folder. When using the one from the framework64\v2.0... then the error doesn't happen.
Also when using either (x86 or x64) ILASM from .net 4.0 (Beta 2) it passes just fine.
So this really looks like a bug in the ILASM of .net 2.0 for x86.

Comment: @Rubens Farias: You're right, I didn't contact Microsoft until now :-) I don't think that will help though. (+1 anyway)

Comment: @Rubens Farias: Yes that would be my next step. But I thought I'll first see if someone here can help me. It doesn't look like a problem of dotfuscator to me (or I did something wrong, maybe with referenced assemblies or so).

Comment: ok; i'll drop this comments, to do not mess with people responses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the issue with ILASM isn't really solved, the following fixed the problem:

- Use ILASM from framework64 folder
  The x64 ILASM works fine. However I couldn't force Dotfuscator to use it.
- Install .net framework 4.0 (Beta 2)
  When ILASM from .net framework 4.0 is used it works just fine.
- Run Dotfuscator with the '/inpl:on' flag
  Dotfuscator support told me to use this flag and it worked fine.
  According to them there shouldn't be any difference in the generated EXE so I'm using this solution currently (The flag is not available in the GUI).

Comment: Just curious, how much ram did you have when you tested this? It could well be that using 64bit ilasm allowed you to go beyond 4GB.

Comment: @Johannes Rudolph: I had 4GB RAM in the system while having these problems. I'm still using the x64 ILASM from .net 2 and it works just fine.

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for getting that information back. Actually you might have hit the threshold earlier (like at 3.2GB), but thanks for letting everyone know what worked for you!

Comment: I opened the Visual Studio 2008 command prompt in admin mode.  I don't have .NET 4.0 installed on my machine yet.  Does this command not work in .NET 3.5?  I keep getting this error....  Dis-assemble: ildasm myTest.dll /out:myTest.il > Re-assemble: ilasm myTest.il /res:myTest.res /dll /key:myTest.snk /out:myTestSN.dll > Error: 'ilasm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Comment: @Mr. MacGyver: ilasm.exe should be in the folder "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727" (that's the .net 2.0 x86 version).